# url rewriting and passing variable

Tags: php, url-rewriting

Hi i'm trying to send data over from a url rewrite page but unfortunately, its not working its just throwing me back to the main page or error page. The template & urlrewrite for **rmbitter** is what i'm trying to do. Currently domain.com/rmbitter.php loads perfectly file. I have a link on domain/boothwall.html and that link looks like this **domain.com/rmbitter.php?ulnk=$usr&slnk=$lnk** the rmbitter.tpl has the $_GET code. My problem I believe is with the rewrite its not allowing the variable to be passed over.

The reason for using the .tpl is because the page has a design layout that is needed. If i build a started rmbitter.php file with a test.html page and a link to rmbitter.php with the variable it works fine.

```
$inc = array(
            'pictures' => 'icons.php',
            'view_images' => 'templates/view_images.tpl',
            'boothw' => 'templates/boothw.tpl',
            'rmbitter' => 'templates/rmbitter.tpl'
            );

//URL rewriting rules...
$rew = array(
            '/view_images_public\/(.*)$/' => 'req=view_images&user=$1', 
            '/boothwall\.html$/' => 'req=boothw',
            '/rmbitter\.php$/' => 'req=rmbitter'
            );
```

url_rewrite.php

```
<?php
//get request
        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        if (strpos($url,'?PHPSESSID=')) $url = substr($url,0,strpos($url,'?PHPSESSID='));
        while (strpos($url,'//') !== false) $url = str_replace('//','/',$url);
        $url = substr($url,strlen(constant('dir')));
        $url_array = explode('/', $url);

//make request string
        $reqstr = '';
        foreach ($url_array as $key => $value)
                $reqstr .= '/'.$value;
        $reqstr = substr($reqstr,1);

//other stuff
    if (substr($reqstr,0,9) != 'index.php') {

        $rewrite['/pages\/(.*)\.html$/'] = 'req=pages&id=$1';
        $rewrite['/static\/(.*)\.html$/'] = 'req=static&id=$1';
        $rewrite['/(.*)\.html$/'] = 'req=$1';
?>
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On        
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Where are these URL rewriting rules actually being applied? What are you using for this?

Comment: see above, i've added the url_rewrite.php file

Comment: I still don't see an actual rewrite happening? Is there a header redirect at some point?

Comment: its rewrite just the page/filename not the domain url itself. so rmbitter.tpl is rewritten to rmbitter.php for displaying. so its not a hard-coded rewrite like seen in .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

I don't 100% understand what your problem is, but the general cure to all GET related mod_rewrite ailments is Query String Append (QSA).

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L, QSA]
```

as the name says, it appends any incoming GET data to the new URL and passes it on to index.php.